# Dynamic header with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi, react-context

Im trying to create a header component that uses data from a rest api to create the navbar.
The issue im having is how to get this data - Ideally i want to be using getStaticProps because it doesnt change much however im not able to use this inside of the _app file.

Right now i am:

- Grabbing the data from the _app file using getInitialProps
- Sending this data to the MyApp component
- Checking when the data is recievied using a function that checks if the data has been returned or not
- Then putting this data through a dispatch function (im using context API) and adding the data to the globalState object under the property headerData
- then using this context in my components that need them.

This process is going on for every page except instead of getInitialProps i use getStaticProps inside of the pages (because i cant use getStaticProps in the _app)

This is no doubt awful design, But im not sure how i can structure this project. The data is vital to the site and even contains what colors should be used ect. Ive been searching endlessly and cannot find how to structure a site built from data stored in a rest API including common components such as headers and footers. Any ideas?

Heres the code for what im working with - (I am not using this for the header anymore though)

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { GlobalContext } from 'context';
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import LandingPage from 'components/landing/LandingPage';

export default function Home(props) {
  const { globalState, dispatch } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);
  // function that checks if the data has been loaded or not
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'header', data: props.head });
    dispatch({ type: 'landing', data: props.res });
  }, [dataLoaded]);
  return (
    <div>
      <LandingPage data={props.data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
  const data = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/landing-page`);
  const res = await data.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data: res,
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const data = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/header`);
  const res = await data.json();
  console.log(context);
  return {
    props: {
      head:res,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: I would like to ask: Does your header only get data one time from API, or does it change on every pages?

Comment: Sorry didnt see this - It never changes